# Decay Feynman diagram

Tags: standard-model, feynman-diagrams, weak-interaction

$$D^0 \to K^+ +\pi^- + \pi^0 + \pi^0$$ cannot occur by first order weak interactions. Could anybody help me confirm this? What I currently have is that the initial charm goes to anti-strange and the anti-up goes to anti-down, both through the $W$ boson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there something wrong with this process? (it will admittedly be suppressed by $|V_{su}|^2\approx \frac{1}{20}$, i.e. "doubly cabbibo suppressed")

[image]

or maybe even replace the Z boson with gluons.